# How to use passed-in parameters for shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I know little about shell script but I want to try to implement some complicated scripts.

Say I have a doitall.sh with the content like:

```
zip -j version_a_en.zip en_filea1.txt en_fileb2.json
```

And a doitall2.sh with the content like:

```
zip -j version_b_en.zip en_fileb1.txt en_fileb2.json
```

How can I use "a" and "en" as parameters so that I can use only one script to handle all the similar requirements. Like

```
./doitall.sh a en
```

or

```
./doitall.sh b fr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commandline parameters `a` and `en` can be accessed in shell scripts using `$1` and `$2`:

```
#! /bin/bash
zip -j version_"$1"_"$2".zip "$2"_filea1.txt "$2"_fileb2.json
```

care has to be taken when you have numbers following them in the text, that is why I always tend to put them in double quotes, but in this case you could leave them out.

Comment: The standard way to delimit the variable name is with braces, as in `"version_${1}_${2}.zip"`, with the double quotes around the whole being necessary in case the arguments themselves contain spaces.